# Save json data into my db using django and postgresql

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I'm working with django and postgres, I've a large json data that i want to save into my db but idk how.
My json data looks like this:

```
  {
    "Name": "some name",
    "Direction": "Street name",
    "City": "City",
    "Region": "Region",
    "DirectionGeo": "Street with geopy",
    "Category": "Category",
    "ExternalCode": "Code",
    "lat": latitude,
    "lon": longitude
  }
```

That's all the data I want to save, can someone give me an advice on how I can save my data into the db using python please

this is my model.py:

```
from django.db import models

  class Bidder(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    geopy_direction = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    lat = models.FloatField(20)
    lon = models.FloatField(20)
```

Comment: you want to save this `json` data in a single field? You can use [JSONFIeld](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField)

Comment: Can you please add your model code?

Comment: there it is, i was looking at some tutorials but all of them are differente so i got confused more and more

Comment: at the moment i only have this table in my db, I want to save it automatically after running another python file that has the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you were trying to consume API data and want to store in your database using python, may this help take reference or in-case i lack to provide correct information, please do let me know

```
import pymysql
import requests
BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
ENDPOINT = 'api/'
json_data = requests.get(BASE_URL+ENDPOINT)
data = json_data.json()
list_data = []
for edata in data:
    list_data.append((edata['EmployeeNo'], edata['Name'], edata['Salary'], edata['Address']))

conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', password='Ashish@123', db='black')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'insert into black_table(EmployeeNo, Name, Salary, Address) values(%s, %s, %s, %s)'
data =  list_data
try:
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    conn.commit()
    print("Data stored to database")
except conn.DatabaseError as message:
    if conn:
        conn.rollback()
        print("Error occured", message)
finally:
    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if conn:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Remember if you were trying to update the data in database, then please alter the query as it may add the duplicate data.

Comment: Does this work for postgresql? I'm new with this, I see if it works